# Where clause for arrays of single column in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm building a small application on `laravel 5.5` where I'm retrieving models with the relationship absence, something like this:

```php
$milestone =  Milestone::where('unique_id', $request->id)
    ->whereDoesntHave('block')
    ->first();
```

This is working fine but when I convert `milestone` variable to an array I'm getting absurd results, I tried:

```php
$milestone =  Milestone::where('unique_id', $request->id)
    ->whereDoesntHave('block', function ($q) use($request){
        foreach($request->milestone as $m)
            $q->where('unique_id', $m);
    })
    ->first();
```

**Edit:**

Following is my relationship:

**Milestone Model:**

```php
public function block()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Team\Block', 'block');
}
```

**Block Model:**

```php
public function block()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

and my block database table:

```php
Schema::create('blocks', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('unique_id');
    $table->string('block_type');
    $table->integer('block_id');
    $table->integer('generic_id');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->integer('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->softDeletes();
});
```

Help me out in this, Thanks

Comment: What kind of relationship `block` is?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `whereIn` rather than a `foreach` with multiple `where` clauses. I.e.

```
 $q->whereIn('unique_id', $mArray);
```

If you chain the `where` clauses together, those are `AND where` clauses.  As an example

```
App\Models\User::where('id', 1)->where('id', 2)->toSql();
"select * from `users` where `id` = ? and `id` = ?"
App\Models\User::whereIn('id', [1,2])->toSql();
"select * from `users` where `id` in (?, ?)"
```

the former gives no results, while the latter gives the results you might expect

Comment: I guess you are right, but while placing so I'm getting the model, but when I see my database it says the relationship exists. what can be the possibilities?

Comment: @NitishKumar i'm not sure what your last comment means exactly, but I've updated my answer to be more clear

Comment: I'm using `whereDoesntHave` clause so that I can get models where `block` relation is not present, but in my case I can see in my database the relationship exists and still I get the output, but if I don't place `whereIn` or `where` clause inside the block query function, I get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Chain `whereDoesntHave()`:

```
$milestone =  Milestone::where('unique_id', $request->id);

foreach($request->milestone as $m) {
    $milestone = $milestone->whereDoesntHave('block', function ($q) use($m) {
        $q->where('unique_id', $m);
    });
}

$milestone = $milestone->first();
```

Or use `whereHas()` with `whereNotIn()`:

```
$milestone =  Milestone::where('unique_id', $request->id)
    ->whereHas('block', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->whereNotIn('unique_id', $request->milestone);
    })
    ->first();
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the update, but both the cases are not giving me desired results, I've updated the relationship in my question. Please check.

Comment: @NitishKumar thanks for relationship update. I can't test it on polymorphic relationships now, but this solution works for all other types of relationships.